# Equation of motion including gear ratio

Tags: control-theory, classical-mechanics, euler-lagrange-equation

Two-mass rotational system has the following form and is represented in following structural diagram.

[image]

where $\tau_e$, $\omega_1$ and $J_m$ - motor torque, angular velocity and moment of inertia

$\tau_s$, $\tau_s$, $\omega_2$ and $J_d$ - shaft torque, load torque, angular velocity and load moment of inertia;

$K_{md}$ - shaft stiffness

**Problem:** how to include a gear ratio $N=\frac{\omega_1}{\omega_2}$ in equation of motion and in in a block diagram respectively?

$L=V-P=J_m \frac{\omega_1^2}{2}+J_d \frac{\omega_2^2}{2}-\frac{K_{md}(\phi_1-\phi_2)^2}{2}$

$V$ - kinetic, and $P$ - potential energy

Here is the Lagrangian for the entire system. And I don’t understand how to insert the gear ratio here?

Comment: Where are the gears located, in-between the shaft and the motor? And the mass of the gears are lumped together with the other masses?

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen All questions - yes!

Comment: What progress have you made up to this point?  Have you reviewed any possibly-similar questions in the physics.SE community?  Is there a book or similar work that has available theorems or statistical information on this topic that you can share?

Comment: @abiessu

1. I wrote Lagrangian for the entire system.
2. Yes, there is no information about it.
3. Yes, there is no information about it. And what does the STATISTICAL information have to do with it?

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen see my edit

Comment: As part of your effort please set the action $V-P$ into Mathjax.

Comment: Statistical information is any available amount of trials having similar initial conditions to the described system.

Comment: @abiessu I don't think it helps, I am trying to develop a mathematical model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont have enough reputation to comment or downvote the existing (accepted) answer.

### Why I think the answer is different

```
[motor]---)--[GB]---)--===shaft=====--)--[load]
          phi1    phi1'             phi2
```

In the presence of a flexible shaft there are **3** angular positions. See the ASCII diagram above. **The important point to note is that the definition of N is *not* $\omega_1/\omega_2$**. It is $\omega_1 / \omega_1'$, and $\omega_1' \neq \omega_2$ when the shaft is in twisted condition. The shaft can be in twisted condition at various times while the system is operating.

In fact the OP has asked

> I have a question right away. If N=1, then the term with the shaft stiffness is lost? This is very strange, how to explain it?

So I am posting [my answer](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/a/44870/33437) to the duplicate question asked the OP at engineering.se.

### My answer at engineering.se

Assuming that the gear box is on the left end of the shaft (i.e. no flexible shaft between motor and gearbox).

1. The angular velocity on the left end of the gear box is $\omega_1$.
2. The angular velocity of the shaft side of the gear box is assumed as $\omega_1' = \frac{\omega_1}{N}$.
3. The angular velocity on the right end of the shaft is $\omega_2$. So the torque on the shaft is $\pm K_m (\frac{\phi_1}{N} - \phi_2)$. (sign to be checked).
4. Because of the way I described the gearbox, $\omega_1' < \omega_1 $. so the torque on the shaft when acting on the motor through the gearbox is $\frac{1}{N}$. This can be seen in the below derivation.
5. Since I have assumed that shaft is directly connected to the load, the torque in the shaft is made available 1:1. This can also be seen in below derivation.

(Below derivation to be verified independently by OP)
$$
L = \frac{J_m \omega_1^2}{2}
+ \frac{J_d \omega_2^2}{2}
+ \frac{Km (\frac{1}{N} \phi_1 - \phi_2)^2}{2}
$$

$$
\frac{d}{dt} \frac{\partial L}{\partial \omega_1}
= \frac{d}{dt} J_m \omega_1
= J_m \frac{d \omega_1}{dt}
$$

$$
\frac{\partial L}{\partial \phi_1}
= \frac{K_m}{\color{red}{N}} (\frac{1}{N} \phi_1 - \phi_2)
$$

Similarly for the other body also (exercise left to you).

$$
\frac{\partial L}{\partial \phi_2}
= -K_m (\frac{1}{N} \phi_1 - \phi_2)
$$

I have not considered the input torque. It can be added to this result.

Comment: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/250286/equations-of-motion-for-two-mass-torsional-oscillator-with-the-gear-train/250291?noredirect=1#comment627297_250291

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4185010/derive-the-equations-of-motion-including-gear-ratios/4185511?noredirect=1#comment8677111_4185511

Comment: "I have not considered the input torque. It can be added to this result." Yes, that we may do very simple

Comment: You have expressed difficulty with EL formulation. That is where I tried helping you out.  The mechanics you did  appeared to me  quite ok.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4271830/equations-of-motion-with-gear-ratios-through-the-lagrangian-with-an-unknown-tran

Answer (score 2):

Directly plug in constant ratio between gear rotation angles which is   the same ratio between  their time derivative angular velocities. If

$$N=\dfrac{{\phi_1}}{{\phi_2}}=\dfrac{\dot{\phi_1}}{\dot{\phi_2}}=\dfrac{\omega_1}{\omega_2}$$

then the action is:

$$L=V-P=\frac{\omega_2^2}{2} \left(J_m N^2 +J_d \right)-\frac{K_{md}}{2}\;(N-1)^2\;\phi_2^2.$$

Comment: I have a question right away. If $N = 1$, then the term with the shaft stiffness is lost? This is very strange, how to explain it?

Comment: With same speeds there is no relative twist angle and so *no torsional energy*. A physical property cannot vanish into thin air.

Comment: Yes, of course, I'm sorry. Could you please supplement the answer with substitutions, i.e. to show more clearly how such a Lagrangian came about?

Comment: Do you know how to derive a simple non-linear pendulum starting with $V-P$ difference of PE,KE energies? If you do such simple examples I am sure you can help yourself. I had down voted and cancelled it.

Comment: Just such a thing confuses me. If we make such substitutions in the Lagrangian, don't we get two Lagrangians? https://ibb.co/820MQKY, that strange

Comment: Please read Hamilton principle $ L= T-V $ etc. It is  energy conservation in different terms.

Comment: I need a more serious clue. I understand the meaning, it just doesn't fit in my head how to correct the Lagrangian. Visualization is much more useful for me now than ignorance.

Comment: https://ibb.co/JRBmLgF

Comment: Please formulate non-linear pendulum or at least the linear pendulum at first. Please  postpone the servo block diagram for the time being.

Comment: Linear pendulum https://ibb.co/w7PtSPf

what next ?

Comment: Maybe I'm not expressing my problem clearly enough. Lagrangian takes into account the energies stored in the moving elements of the system. Generalized coordinates are taken that do not "interact" with each other (formally). This relationship in the mechanism is taken into account through the gear ratio. How to include it in the Lagrangian in order to obtain the equation of motion and, based on it, obtain a block diagram for modeling, for example, in simulink.

Comment: https://d2vlcm61l7u1fs.cloudfront.net/media%2Fe3d%2Fe3d8b55d-f905-41d0-b7fa-d53be32fb715%2FphphL0I0P.png

here these things appear, but it is not clear to me how they were obtained ???

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4185010/derive-the-equations-of-motion-including-gear-ratios

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4271830/equations-of-motion-with-gear-ratios-through-the-lagrangian-with-an-unknown-tran