# Derive the equations of motion, including gear ratios

Tags: control-theory, classical-mechanics, euler-lagrange-equation

Continuing the topic [Equation of motion including gear ratio](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4184435/equation-of-motion-including-gear-ratio)

I have found some answers to questions, but not all. The following drawing gave me a hint.

[image]

Here are the equations of motion that include gear ratios.

Each of the equations corresponds to the motion of the corresponding generalized coordinate, and in this equation it remains unchanged, but the rest are "fitted" to it with the help of gear ratios.

**But my question is:** explain to me how the Lagrangian was composed to obtain such equations of motion and is this result correct at all?

**That is, help reproduce the result.**

I would be very glad and grateful for your help!

The code in Mathematica reproduces an attempt to obtain the same results, but to no avail.

```
Clear["Derivative"]

ClearAll["Global`*"]

K = Sum[1/2 Subscript[J, i] D[Subscript[\[Phi], i][t], t]^2, {i, 2}];


U = Sum[1/2 Subscript[c, 
     10 i + i + 
      1] (Subscript[\[Phi], i][t] - 
       Subscript[\[CapitalPhi], i + 1][t])^2, {i, 1}];

L = ReplaceAll[K - U, 
   Subscript[\[CapitalPhi], 2][
     t] -> (Subscript[r, 1]/Subscript[r, 2]) Subscript[\[Phi], 2][t]];

eq1 = D[D[L, Derivative[1][Subscript[\[Phi], 1]][t]], t] - 
    D[L, Subscript[\[Phi], 1][t]] == Subscript[T, 1][t];

eq1 = D[D[L, Derivative[1][Subscript[\[Phi], 2]][t]], t] - 
     D[L, Subscript[\[Phi], 2][t]] == Subscript[T, 2][t] // Simplify;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $d_1=0$ (It is not clear to me how the dissipation actuates here) we have

$$
\cases{
\phi_1^* r_1 = \phi_2^* r_2\\
\phi_2^* = \phi_2\\
K = \frac 12 J_1\dot\phi_1^2+\frac 12 J_2\dot \phi_2^2\\
U = \frac 12 c_1\left(\phi_1-\phi_2^*\right)^2\\
L = K - U\\
\left(\nabla_{\phi_1',\phi_2'}L\right)'-\nabla_{\phi_1,\phi_2}L=(T_1(t),T_2(t))
}
$$

so we have finally

$$
\cases{
J_1\ddot\phi_1+c_1\phi_1= c_1\frac{r_2}{r_1}\phi_2 + T_1(t)\\
J_2\left(\frac{r_1}{r_2}\right)^2\ddot\phi_2 + c_1\phi_2=c_1\frac{r_1}{r_2}\phi_1+\left(\frac{r_1}{r_2}\right)^2T_2(t)
}
$$

Comment: Thank you very much! Can this approach be extended to a three-mass system?

Comment: This process can be extended to any number $n$ of independent masses.

Comment: And how will the calculation change if the rigid shaft is installed after the gearbox, i.e. on a slow-moving shaft? i mean that https://i.stack.imgur.com/nNEzU.png

Comment: In this case $U = \frac 12 c_1\left(\phi_2^*-\phi_2\right)^2$

Comment: see my code in Mathematica, I was unable to reproduce the result somewhere error.

Comment: Sorry, I seem to be deceiving both myself and you. Everything is reproduced, it seems, it is only necessary to make a transformation in the second expression, namely to multiply the equations of state by the square $(r_1/r_2)^2$ Check me out just in case.

Comment: Include in your MATHEMATICA code the following command: `Solve[{eq1, 
   eq2}, { (Subscript[\[Phi], 1]^\[Prime]\[Prime])[t], (
    Subscript[\[Phi], 2]^\[Prime]\[Prime])[t]}] // Expand`

Comment: +, i understand this trick, that work