# Equations of motion with gear ratios through the Lagrangian with an unknown transformation of the angular positions of lumped masses

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, control-theory, classical-mechanics, euler-lagrange-equation

I need advice, I'm confused.

[Derive the equations of motion, including gear ratios](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4185010/derive-the-equations-of-motion-including-gear-ratios)

[Equation of motion including gear ratio](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4184435/equation-of-motion-including-gear-ratio)

[image]

System contains two lumped masses with angular velocity vectors $\boldsymbol{\omega}_1$, $\boldsymbol{\omega}_2$, angular positions vectors $\boldsymbol{\theta}_1$,$\boldsymbol{\theta}_2$, inertia matrices $\boldsymbol{J}_1,\boldsymbol{J}_2$, these masses are connected through a flexible shaft with stiffness matrix $\boldsymbol{c}_1$. $\boldsymbol{d}_1=\boldsymbol{0}$.

Generalized coordinates:

$q=\begin{bmatrix}\boldsymbol{\omega}_1\\\boldsymbol{\omega}_2\\\boldsymbol{\theta}_1\\\boldsymbol{\theta}_2\end{bmatrix}$

Kinetic energy of the system:

$T=\frac{1}{2}\boldsymbol{\omega}_1^T\boldsymbol{J}_1\boldsymbol{\omega}_1+\frac{1}{2}\boldsymbol{\omega}_2^T\boldsymbol{J}_2\boldsymbol{\omega}_2$

I have time-dependent transfer matrix $A(t)$ of the angular velocity vector $\boldsymbol{\omega}_1$ into the angular velocity vector $\boldsymbol{\omega}_2$, the structure of this matrix is known:

$\boldsymbol{\omega}_1=\boldsymbol{A}(t)\boldsymbol{\omega}_2$

To take into account the gear ratio between the angular generalized coordinates $\boldsymbol{\theta}_1$,$\boldsymbol{\theta}_2$, there must be a matrix $\boldsymbol{B}(t)$, i.e.

$\boldsymbol{\theta}_1=\boldsymbol{B}(t)\boldsymbol{\theta}_2$

*But matrix $\boldsymbol{B}(t)$ is unknown.*

By integrating the vector of the angular velocity of the first mass, one can obtain the vector of the angular position of the first mass, and then:

$\boldsymbol{\theta}_2=\int \boldsymbol{A}^{-1}(t) \boldsymbol{\omega}_2dt=\boldsymbol{A}^{-1}(t)\boldsymbol{\theta}_2-\int (\frac{d}{dt}\boldsymbol{A}^{-1}(t))\boldsymbol{\theta}_2dt$

Than, potential energy of the system:

$V=\boldsymbol{c}_1\cdot(\boldsymbol{i}_1(\boldsymbol{v}\boldsymbol{v}^T)\boldsymbol{i}_1+\boldsymbol{i}_2(\boldsymbol{v}\boldsymbol{v}^T)\boldsymbol{i}_2+\boldsymbol{i}_3(\boldsymbol{v}\boldsymbol{v}^T)\boldsymbol{i}_3)\cdot\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\1\end{bmatrix}$

where $\boldsymbol{v}=(\boldsymbol{\theta}_1-(\boldsymbol{A}^{-1}(t)\boldsymbol{\theta}_2-\int (\frac{d}{dt}\boldsymbol{A}^{-1}(t))\boldsymbol{\theta}_2dt))$

$i_1=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$

$i_2=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 & 0\\0 & 1 & 0\\0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$

$i_3=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$

Lagrangian $L=T-V$

**Problem:** Matrix $\boldsymbol{B}(t)$ is unknown. Lagrangian contains the integral of an unknown function $\int (\frac{d}{dt}\boldsymbol{A}^{-1}(t))\boldsymbol{\theta}_2dt$. How to derive the equation of motion $\frac{d}{d(\boldsymbol{\omega}_1,\boldsymbol{\omega}_2,\boldsymbol{\theta}_1,\boldsymbol{\theta}_2)}L$?

**EDIT (thanks to @Cesareo):**

```
Clear["Derivative"];

ClearAll["Global`*"];

Remove[c, J, A];

pars = {Subscript[J, 1] = 1, Subscript[J, 2] = 1, c = 10, A[t] = 2};

s = NDSolve[{M'[t] + M[t] == -Subscript[\[Theta], 1]'[t] + 1, 
    Subscript[J, 1] D[D[Subscript[\[Theta], 1][t], t], t] + 
      D[\[Lambda][t], t] + 
      c (Subscript[\[Theta], 1][t] - Subscript[\[Theta], 2][t]) == 
     M[t], Subscript[J, 2] D[D[Subscript[\[Theta], 2][t], t], t] - 
      D[\[Lambda][t], t] A[t] - \[Lambda][t] D[A[t], t] - 
      c (Subscript[\[Theta], 1][t] - Subscript[\[Theta], 2][t]) == 0, 
    D[D[Subscript[\[Theta], 1][t], t], t] - 
      A[t] D[D[Subscript[\[Theta], 2][t], t], t] - 
      D[A[t], t] D[Subscript[\[Theta], 2][t], t] == 0, M[0] == 0, 
    Subscript[\[Theta], 1][0] == 0, Subscript[\[Theta], 2][0] == 0, 
    Subscript[\[Theta], 1]'[0] == 0.1, 
    Subscript[\[Theta], 2]'[0] == 1/2 0.1, \[Lambda][0] == 
     0}, {Subscript[\[Theta], 1], Subscript[\[Theta], 
    2], \[Lambda]}, {t, 100}];

Plot[{Evaluate[Subscript[\[Theta], 1]'[t] /. s], 
   Evaluate[Subscript[\[Theta], 2]'[t] /. s]}, {t, 0, 100}, 
  PlotRange -> Full];

Plot[{Evaluate[\[Lambda][t] /. s]}, {t, 0, 100}, PlotRange -> Full]

Solve[Subscript[\[Theta], 1]'[t] - A[t] Subscript[\[Theta], 2]'[t] == 
  0, Subscript[\[Theta], 2]'[t]]
```

***EDIT №2:***
$$
\cases{
J_1\dot\omega_1 +\dot\lambda+c(\theta_1-A\theta_2) = T_1\\
J_2\dot\omega_2-\dot\lambda A-\lambda\dot A-c(\theta_1-A\theta_2)= T_2\\
\dot\omega_1-A\dot\omega_2-\dot A\omega_2 = 0
}
$$

***EDIT №3:***

```
Clear["Derivative"]

ClearAll["Global`*"]

Remove[c, J, A]

pars = {Subscript[J, 1] = 1, Subscript[J, 2] = 2, c = 1000, 
   A[t] = 2 + 0.1 Sin[0.1 t]};

s = NDSolve[{M'[t] + M[t] == -Subscript[\[Theta], 1]'[t] + 1, 
    Subscript[J, 1] D[D[Subscript[\[Theta], 1][t], t], t] + 
      D[\[Lambda][t], t] - 
      c (Subscript[\[Theta], 1][
          t] - (A[t] Subscript[\[Theta], 2][t] - 
           Subscript[\[CapitalTheta], 2][t])) == M[t], 
    Subscript[J, 2] D[D[Subscript[\[Theta], 2][t], t], t] - 
      D[\[Lambda][t], t] A[t] - \[Lambda][t] D[A[t], t] - 
      c (Subscript[\[Theta], 1][
          t] - (A[t] Subscript[\[Theta], 2][t] - 
           Subscript[\[CapitalTheta], 2][t])) == 0, 
    D[D[Subscript[\[Theta], 1][t], t], t] - 
      A[t] D[D[Subscript[\[Theta], 2][t], t], t] - 
      D[A[t], t] D[Subscript[\[Theta], 2][t], t] == 0, 
    Subscript[\[CapitalTheta], 2]'[t] == 
     D[A[t], t] Subscript[\[Theta], 2][t], M[0] == 0, 
    Subscript[\[Theta], 1][0] == 0, Subscript[\[Theta], 2][0] == 0, 
    Subscript[\[Theta], 1]'[0] == 0, 
    Subscript[\[Theta], 2]'[0] == 0, \[Lambda][0] == 0, 
    Subscript[\[CapitalTheta], 2][0] == 0}, {Subscript[\[Theta], 1], 
    Subscript[\[Theta], 2], \[Lambda], Subscript[\[CapitalTheta], 
    2]}, {t, 500}];

Plot[{Evaluate[Subscript[\[Theta], 1]'[t] /. s], 
   Evaluate[Subscript[\[Theta], 2]'[t] /. s]}, {t, 0, 500}, 
  PlotRange -> Full];

Plot[{Evaluate[
    Subscript[\[Theta], 1][t]/Subscript[\[Theta], 2][t] /. s], 
   A[t]}, {t, 0, 500}, PlotRange -> Full];
```

Comment: Are you sure that the stiffness is zero? Because, wouldn't that essentially imply no shaft? Instead, maybe you meant infinite stiffness, such that the shaft acts as a rigid connection?

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen $\boldsymbol{d}_1$ is not stiffness, stiffness  is $\boldsymbol{c}_1$. $\boldsymbol{d}_1$ - friction

Comment: Hint. Use Lagrange multipliers to include the restrictions.

Comment: @Cesareo I think at such a replacement? 
$\boldsymbol{v}=(\boldsymbol{\theta}_1-(\boldsymbol{A}^{-1}(t)\boldsymbol{\theta}_2-\boldsymbol{\theta}^{'}_2)$, where $\dot{\boldsymbol{\theta}^{'}_2}=\frac{d}{dt}\boldsymbol{A}^{-1}(t))\boldsymbol{\theta}_2$ it is correct?

Comment: @Cesareo This is a good idea as an idea. But, pay attention to the fact that the $ B $ matrix is unknown, I wrote about it. It may sound strange, but nevertheless it is. This is just a "tentative" notation for some kind of matrix, and more precisely, the transformation of the vector of angular positions is calculated using this subtracted integration. I mean what is most likely $\boldsymbol{\theta}_1=\int \boldsymbol{A}(t) \boldsymbol{\omega}_2dt=\boldsymbol{A}(t)\boldsymbol{\theta}_2-\int (\frac{d}{dt}\boldsymbol{A}(t))\boldsymbol{\theta}_2dt$

Comment: I believe the $\omega_1=A(t)\,\omega_2$ constraint is actually non-holonomic. It has been a while since I applied the Euler-Lagrange equation, and probably even longer with constraints. However, according Wikipedia Euler-Lagrange mechanics can only deal with holonomic constraints.

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen Imagine an electric motor connected to a load through a variator. The variator is a gearbox with a variable gear ratio. A classic drive, just with this feature. The Lagrangian principle is quite applicable for such cases, as far as I understand.

Comment: As far as I remember, the finite stiffness introduces an extra torque, $T_{12} = c_1(\theta_1-\theta_2)$. Then you have $J_1\dot \omega_1 = T_1-T_{12}$ and $J_2\dot \omega_2 = T_2+T_{12}$.

Comment: @dtn If the coefficients change in time, then it is a time_varying system, but the equations should remain the same.

Comment: @Arastas $\boldsymbol{\omega}_1$ and $\boldsymbol{\omega}_2$ are related as follows $\boldsymbol{\omega}_1=\boldsymbol{A}(t)\boldsymbol{\omega}_2$. Vector of angular positions $\boldsymbol{\theta}_1$, i.e. $\boldsymbol{\theta}_1=\int \boldsymbol{A}(t) \boldsymbol{\omega}_2dt=\boldsymbol{A}(t)\boldsymbol{\theta}_2-\int (\frac{d}{dt}\boldsymbol{A}(t))\boldsymbol{\theta}_2dt$. That is from $\boldsymbol{\omega}_1=\boldsymbol{A}(t)\boldsymbol{\omega}_2$ it does not follow $\boldsymbol{\theta}_1=\boldsymbol{A}(t)\boldsymbol{\theta}_2$ Is not it so?

Comment: @dtn You are right, $\omega_1(t) = A(t)\omega_2(t)$ for all $t$ does not generally imply $\theta_1(t) = A(t)\theta_2(t)$ as $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ are solutions of an ode. But is does not change the dynamics, i.e., it is the same ode.

Comment: @Arastas Here! And I need to somehow figure out how to evaluate the matrix $B(t)$ that transform $\boldsymbol{\theta}_1$ to $\boldsymbol{\theta}_2$, i.e. $\boldsymbol{\theta}_1=B(t)\boldsymbol{\theta}_2$, from $\boldsymbol{\omega}_1$,$\boldsymbol{\omega}_2$,$\boldsymbol{\theta}_1$,$\boldsymbol{\theta}_2$ and $\boldsymbol{A}(t)$

Comment: @dtn Then you probably need to write the solution of your system. It is a linear time-varying system, and its solution is given in the terms of the fundamental matrix. It is not obvious if you can compute it without explicitly solving the ode for the given $A(t)$.

Comment: @Arastas Could you demonstrate what has been said in the form of a couple of formulas. They are interested because the general Lagrangian is rather complicated and I can hardly find an exhaustive solution for the equations of motion, especially taking into account their high dimension and variable matrices. Clarify please.

Comment: @Cesareo re-write the comment that suggested the formula using Lagrangian multipliers.

Comment: @Cesareo Can you clarify the wording "no use to include"? Does it mean "it is possible, but the Lagrange multiplier will not play any role in this case" or "it is absolutely impossible for some reason"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, following the discussion in the comments, here are some equations. Note that I have no idea what is the dynamics of your gearbox, so I assume something simple and approximative.

We have four (vector) states: $\theta_1$, $\omega_1$, $\theta_2$, and $\omega_2$. What we know for sure is that $\dot{\theta}_1(t) = \omega_1(t)$ and $\dot{\theta}_2(t) = \omega_2(t)$. Suppose that the torque $T_1$ acts on $\dot{\omega}_1$, e.g., it is a motor, and the torque $T_2$ acts on $\dot{\omega}_2$, e.g., it is the load torque or a friction.

Now we need to model the gearbox. Define the internal variable $\delta$; the dynamics of $\delta$ is assumed to be $\dot{\delta}(t) = \omega_1(t) - A(t)\omega_2(t)$, where $A(t)$ is the time-varying gear ratio matrix.  Then the torque due to the stiffness is $T_{12}(t) = c \delta(t)$, where $c$ is the constant finite stiffness.

Finally, the equations are
$$
\begin{aligned}
\dot{\theta}_1(t) &= \omega_1(t),\\
\dot{\theta}_2(t) &= \omega_2(t),\\
J_1(t)\dot{\omega}_1 &= T_1(t) - c\delta(t), \\
J_2(t)\dot{\omega}_2 &= T_2(t) + c\delta(t), \\
\dot{\delta}(t) &= \omega_1(t) - A(t)\omega_2(t),
\end{aligned}
$$
where $J_1$ and $J_2$ are the time-varying inertias.

Note that for the constant gear ratio $A(t)\equiv A$ we can eliminate the dynamics of $\delta$ replacing $\delta(t) = \theta_1(t) - A\theta_2(t)$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! He cleared up some things I didn't understand in my head. Now do I know what to do? I need to compose a Lagrangian that will give me such equations of motion.

Comment: Note that $\omega_1(t)-A(t)\omega_2(t) = 0$

Comment: @Cesareo Why should it be so for a finite stiffness? For example, if the stiffness is zero, you have $\omega_2=0$.

Comment: @Arastas $\omega_1-A(t)\omega_2 = 0$ is a restriction. It always is verified.

Comment: @Cesareo If you think about a very flexible joint, at some moment of time even the rotation directions are opposite.

Comment: You made the right remark, because elastic shaft and speed limitation are contradictions. This is confirmed by modeling. If a limitation is introduced, the stiffness factor ceases to affect the transient processes in the system.

Comment: Can you write a Lagrangian that gives this system of equations of motion?

Comment: Welcome! https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130663/discussion-between-cesareo-and-dtn

Answer (score 2):

Having in consideration the document about non holonomic constraints from a reputable source, [here](https://www.physics.uci.edu/%7Etanedo/files/teaching/P3318S13/Sec_05_nonholonomic.pdf) (**item 6** - constraint linearity on $\omega_1,\omega_2$) we can dare to develop a Lagrangian model as follows

$$
L(\omega,\theta,\lambda) = \frac 12\omega_1^TJ_1\omega_1+\frac 12\omega_2^TJ_2\omega_2-\frac 12(\theta_1-\theta_2)^T c(\theta_1-\theta_2)+\lambda(\omega_1-A\omega_2)
$$

thus obtaining the movement equations

$$
\cases{
J_1\dot\omega_1 +\dot\lambda+c(\theta_1-\theta_2) = T_1\\
J_2\dot\omega_2-\dot\lambda A-\lambda\dot A-c(\theta_1-\theta_2)= T_2\\
\dot\omega_1-A\dot\omega_2-\dot A\omega_2 = 0\\
\theta_1 = \int_0^t A(\tau)\dot\theta_2(\tau) d\tau
}
$$

Here $\omega_i = \dot\theta_i$

NOTE

This ODE system is equivalent to

$$
\cases{
J_1\dot\omega_1+\dot\lambda+c(\Theta_1-\theta_2)=T_1\\
J_2\dot\omega_2-\dot\lambda A- \lambda\dot A-c(\Theta_1-\theta_2)=T_2\\
\dot\omega_1-A\dot\omega_2-\dot A\omega_2=0\\
\dot\Theta_1 = A\dot\theta_2\\
\dot\theta_2 = \omega_2
}
$$

EDIT

Included a MATHEMATICA script to simulate a very simple system

```
Clear[A, J1, J2, c]
sols = Solve[{J1 dw1 + dlambda + c (Theta1 - theta2) == T1, 
              J2 dw2 - dlambda A - lambda dA - c (Theta1 -theta2) == T2, 
              dw1 - A dw2 - dA w2 == 0}, {dw1, dw2,dlambda}][[1]] // FullSimplify;
odes0 = sols /. Rule -> Equal;
odest = odes0 /. {w1 -> w1[t], w2 -> w2[t], lambda -> lambda[t], Theta1 -> Theta1[t], theta1 -> theta1[t], theta2 -> theta2[t], A -> A[t], dA -> A'[t], dlambda -> lambda'[t], dw1 -> w1'[t], dw2 -> w2'[t]};

tmax = 10;
A[t_] := 2 + 0.1 Sin[0.1 t]
J1 = 1;
J2 = 2;
c = 500;
T1 = 1;
T2 = 2;
odestot = Join[odest, {theta1'[t] == w1[t], theta2'[t] == w2[t], Theta1'[t] == A[t] w2[t]}];
cinits = {theta1[0] == 0, theta2[0] == 0, w1[0] == 0, w2[0] == 0, lambda[0] == 0, Theta1[0] == 0};
solode = NDSolve[Join[odestot, cinits], {w1, w2, theta1, theta2, Theta1, lambda}, {t, 0, tmax}];

Plot[Evaluate[{w1[t], w2[t]} /. solode], {t, 0, tmax}]
Plot[Evaluate[{theta1[t], theta2[t]} /. solode], {t, 0, tmax}]
Plot[Evaluate[{Theta1[t]} /. solode], {t, 0, tmax}]
Plot[Evaluate[{lambda[t]} /. solode], {t, 0, tmax}]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have a few questions.
1. We discussed a related problem with you and you proposed a solution here.  https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4185511/656085 
There, the gear ratio was included in the term of the potential energy from elastic deformation. Why is the difference $(\theta_1-\theta_2)^Tc(\theta_1-\theta_2)$ in this Lagrangian written without taking into account the gear ratio matrix?

Comment: 2. The third equation is the derivative of the constraint with respect to time and is obtained from considerations of the fulfillment of the given constraint. But, the restriction must be zero, and the derivative of zero does not always mean that the function is zero, it can be either zero or a constant, and in both cases the derivative is zero. But, if the derivative of the constraint is zero, but the constraint itself is just a contant, then it is not met? What is the rationale behind the third equation?

Comment: 3. Do I understand correctly that for numerical modeling it is necessary to correctly set the initial conditions for the constraints to be fulfilled.

Comment: 1. It is easy to include the gear ratio,
2. The derivative of $f(x) = 0$ is $f'(x) = 0$.
3. The ODE's reduction to differential form should be accompanied by coherence in the initial conditions to integrate conveniently.

Comment: I have simulated this system of differential equations. The system becomes unstable when I make $A ≠ 1$. The code in Mathematica is attached to the new edition of the topic.

Comment: There is a sign error in the potential energy: it should be $(-)$. Now it is corrected.

Comment: No, that's not the point! For the system to be modeled normally, it is necessary to include the gear ratio $A$ in the potential energy from elastic deformation $c(\theta_1-A\theta_2)$. I showed this in another EDIT №2. And here we return to the first problem - how to determine this gear ratio matrix, i.e. between angular positions $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$, if we know only gear ratio matrix between $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$ :)))

Comment: Please, see this system (Edit №3). Is that correct?

$\begin{cases} -c \left(-A(t) \theta _2(t)+\theta _1(t)+\Theta _2(t)\right)+J_1 \theta _1''(t)+\lambda '(t)=T_1(t) \\ -\lambda (t) A'(t)-c \left(-A(t) \theta _2(t)+\theta _1(t)+\Theta _2(t)\right)-A(t) \lambda '(t)+J_2
   \theta _2''(t)=0 \\ -A'(t) \theta _2'(t)-A(t) \theta _2''(t)+\theta _1''(t)=0 \\ \Theta _2'(t)=\theta _2(t) A'(t) \end{cases}$

Comment: Good idea. Included as a NOTE to the answer.

Comment: Note that $\dot\theta_1 = A\dot\theta_2$ then $\theta_1 = \int_0^t A(\tau)\dot\theta_2(\tau)d\tau$

Comment: Yes, and then $\int_{0}^\tau A(\tau)\dot{\theta_2}(\tau)d\tau=A(t)\theta_2(t)-\int_{0}^\tau\frac{dA(\tau)}{d\tau}\theta_2(\tau)=A(t)\theta_2-\Theta_2$

Comment: Hey! Now we need to come up with a Lagrangian that will give these equations of motion :)))

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130663/discussion-between-cesareo-and-dtn).

Comment: I ask for clarification. Can this method be used for multiple constraints?

Comment: Yes. Of course. This formulation is a matricial one.

Comment: hey! I want to clarify something else. In the considered two-mass system, the masses move in accordance with the task signal and the gear ratios / matrices $A$. Suppose there is a certain law of motion in time $\omega_z$, and I want the second mass $\omega_2$ to move according to this law. This must be achieved either by adding to the reference signal, OR by adjusting the gear ratio / transfer matrix $A$. What will the terms with Lagrange multipliers look like in this case? Like this?: $...+\lambda_1(\omega_1-A\omega_2)+\lambda_2(\omega_2-\omega_z)$

Comment: If you want to follow a motion law $\omega_z$ then we have a control problem. Now we will produce inputs $T_1,T_2$ such that $\omega_2$ follows $\omega_z$. This can be done within an optimal control formulation.

Comment: Optimal control is already too broad a step into an area that is too complex for this task. Is it possible to solve the problem in the field of Lagrange multipliers? Let's say, not at the expense of an additional input, but at the expense of adjusting the gear ratio?

Comment: Lagrangian multipliers serve to handle restrictions. To make $\omega_2=\omega_z$ is a restriction and it is quite different from "... $\omega_2$ follows $\omega_z$ ..."

Comment: Perhaps submitting a new question focusing the control needs, would be better.

Comment: hello! I have not dealt with this issue for some time, and now I have returned to it and am trying to figure it out. I need your little help. What should the Lagrangian look like to get the last two equations in the system of equations? https://ibb.co/p1TZcWf